# Horizontal rule underneath text AND image

Tags: html, css

so I am currently trying to add a horizontal rule underneath a text and image however, when I put the `<hr />` underneath the closing div tag, it only displays underneath the text instead of underneath both. I will add my code so that you can see what I've done so far!

```
<div class ="services-homepage">
    <img src="http://dev.southlandautomation.com/skin/frontend/boilerplate/southlandautomation/images/automation1.jpg"  style="float:left "/>

    <h4>Southland Automation specializes in industrial automation sales, service, and repairs. Southland delivers world-class motor control support for electrical support for equipment including drives, soft starts, and PLC. Southland also houses a full repair facility with capabilities to repair obsolete and legacy devices.</h4 style="float:right">
</div>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `float:left` of the image tag, you need to clear it later on with `<div style="clear:left"></div>` in the same element to stop it from overfloating:

```html
<div class="services-homepage">
  <img src="http://dev.southlandautomation.com/skin/frontend/boilerplate/southlandautomation/images/automation1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px" />

  <h4>Southland Automation specializes in industrial automation sales, service, and repairs. Southland delivers world-class motor control support for electrical support for equipment including drives, soft starts, and PLC. Southland also houses a full repair facility with capabilities to repair obsolete and legacy devices.</h4>
  <div style="clear:left"></div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Comment: This worked! I have another question if I may ask!  I'm having trouble creating some space between the image and the text yet it's not working in the way I'd like, I've tried using the padding tag in css but it's not working.

Comment: @Mhernandez `margin-right: 10px` in image will add 10px on the right. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you add `style="clear: both;` to your `hr` it will prevent the horizontal rule from displaying to the right of the floated image.

```
<hr style="clear: both;" />
```

I also noticed you added a style attribute to your closing `</h4 style="...">`. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: Haha thanks! Initially it was displaying as an error when I put it in the opening h4 tag so I just put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers here are good but I wanted to add a bit of a spin and separate solution just in case the floats really need to be there for some odd reason.

Consider the following:

```
.services-homepage{
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
}
```

This will work for you too. ;)

See [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPLaEb) here

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it was not working. Thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using CSS borders rather than horizontal rules for most things.

You can apply `border-bottom` to a wrapping div.  I.e.:

```
<style type="text.css">

div.services-homepage {
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

</style>
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/o3ze26yy/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, without adding extra element to the page:

```css
.services-homepage:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-homepage">
  <img src="http://dev.southlandautomation.com/skin/frontend/boilerplate/southlandautomation/images/automation1.jpg" style="float:left " />

  <h4>Southland Automation specializes in industrial automation sales, service, and repairs. Southland delivers world-class motor control support for electrical support for equipment including drives, soft starts, and PLC. Southland also houses a full repair facility with capabilities to repair obsolete and legacy devices.</h4>

</div>
<hr />
```